# What does it mean stir at room temperature overnight?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, synthesis

It was mentioned in synthetic procedure to "stir at room temperature overnight".

What does this mean?  (I want the exact duration for how long should I keep stirring.)

How is it possible to carry this out during day time, due to my limitations?

Comment: Do you have method for following the progress of your reaction? The procedure means that the reaction is not time sensitive once it has gone to completion, it can be left running. It may be that it takes 12+ hours to go to completion. Yes, it can be worked up before that at the risk of a reduced yield.

Comment: It can be calculated. the needed start and stop of stirring  depends on the geographic latitude, longitude, date and if there is meant astronomical night, nautical night, citizen night or Sun (sunset-sunrise) night. // Now seriously, overnight intentionally means the exact duration is not critical. Unless there is light sensitivity, it can be done over working hours too. doing so overnight means more handy waiting while sleeping.

Comment: If the instructions say that then "exact" time is not an issue. Probably anything around 12±6hr will work.

Comment: There may be magnetic stirring bars available for the lab or even your local high school. Simply get one(or ask prof where it is), put it in the beaker and put the beaker in a rotary. Then go to sleep.

Comment: "Stir at room temperature overnight" is lazy researcher's way of saying the next morning that s/he forgot to write down when the stirring started. You are correct. Duration is important.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a solution, you may use a magnetic stirrer to stir your solution overnight, preferably kept in a fume hood or well ventilated area. Depending on the volatility of your solution you might want to cover it to prevent evaporation and weight loss.

Comment: or run it under a nitrogen blanket

Comment: What is the point of stirring a solution? Force of habit perhaps. A two phase mixture, certainly.

Comment: @user55119 diffusion is very slow for centimer-scale lengths.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMAYOvlzD6w